# Using reference variable for refering static members

Tags: java

Im just a beginner .. My query is .. We can refer static members using reference variables..  But reference variable contains address of object which contains non-static members of the class .. How is it working?

Comment: It basically comes to the idea that everything is a pointer to somewhere in memory.  You're basically pointing your "instance" or "reference" variable to the memory location of the `static` field.  By it's nature, these address space cannot be modified.  I'm hoping some more how is more articulate than I can make that clearer :P

Comment: So it refers in the static pool ?

Comment: [*This*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-is-a-static-method-and-a-static-variable-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-in-sta) might help (to confus you further ;))

Comment: @MadProgrammer I believe you err when you say that the address space cannot be modified. As long as the variable is not `static final` it should be modifiable.

Comment: @RohitJain I believe the question is sufficiently different while the answer relates to the same mechanics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are referencing a class (not an object mind you) as for example `MyLasterGun` then the resources for that class will be located and loaded. Part of the resources for the class are its variables. Non-static variables are instantiated once the class is instantiated but `static` variables are instantiated as soon as the class is loaded. Consider this code:

```
public class MyLaserGun
{
    public static String target = "Major Movie Metropolis";
    public Timer countdown;

    public void MyLasterGun()
    {
        countdown = new Timer();
    }
}

public class FortressOfDoom
{
    private String target;

    public void FortressOfDoom()
    {
        target = MyLaserGun.target;

        // To access the timer, an actual instance must be created
        MyLaserGun pewpew = new MyLaserGun();
        pewpew.countdown.cancel();
    }
}
```

You could access the target by calling `MyLaserGun.target`but you can't access the countdown unless you instantiated the class creating a new object.

Also, do not confuse `static` variables, which you can edit just fine, with `static final` variables which are constants and cannot be changed.

More information on when static variables are initialised can be found in [When does static class initialization happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization).

**Update**
Consider the updated example.

Comment: I'll write something up and edit my solution. Bear with me!

Comment: Im sorry if i said something foolish

Answer (score 0):

Static member means its property of class. where non-static member means property of object.

take an example of Bird class so if i say canFly = true is static property of Bird class.

but say suppose now you want to describe only those Bird who can not fly then you can use

```
Bird penguin = new Bird();
penguin.canFly= false;//canFly is static variable.
```

that means now you are decribing only those bird what cannot fly.

where as

```
penguin.homeTown = coldArea; // is non-static property.
```