# Memory Scope of Static Members in JAVA

Tags: java, variables, static, scope

This question is regarding memory management & GC in java.

Since java does not have true static classes like C#, what is the scope of static members in a class such as below:

```
public class Test {
public static String myVariable;
}
```

Lets say Test.myVariable is set / called in another class Foo.

Is Test.myVariable kept alive for as long as Foo is alive?

OR

Will Test.myVariable be kept alive for as long as the application domain is ?

When would myVariable go out of scope ?

Comment: not at all. public static members are accessible by any class that has access to `Test`.

Comment: I'm considering scenario where Test.myVariable was accessed once.

Comment: All, I've clarified the question as it deals with memory scope not access scope.

Comment: What did you find in the documentation that you did not understand? It sounds as though it should be in scope for as long as `Test` is loaded.

Comment: @PJTraill what do u mean by loaded? Test would never be instantiated it self. Only Test.myVariable is called - at which point does it go out of scope ?

Comment: What I meant is that – as Paul remarked – it is accessible to any class that has access to _Test_, but that if _Test_ is loaded by some _ClassLoader_ and accessed via Reflection (rather than accessed by other code in the same code base), it need not stay loaded for ever.

Comment: Thanks @PJTraill Please review the question as it deals with memory management not accessibility modifier keywords (public, protected, etc).

Comment: Are you using “scope” in the sense of the Specification: (Scope of a declaration)[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3]? Scope of a declaration is “is the region of the program within which the entity ... can be referred to using a simple name, provided it is visible”, i.e. it is a static rather than a dynamic property, and has nothing to do with memory management. Perhaps you need to change your terminology.

Comment: Question is about variable memory scope. I'm not sure why the verbiage is so confusing to many readers. Saying "variable is out of scope" always meant memory scope in other words Garbage Collected or eligible for - at least for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean when it will be available for the garbage collection.static members are candidate for garbage collection when the class loader which was responsible for loading the class is itself a candidate for garbage collection.
For example suppose class Test was loaded by a class loader object say loader1.So when loader1 is eligible for GC then class Test and its static variable ,in this case myVariable are also eligible for GC
Check out [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html%23jls-12.7)

Comment: Thanks. So in this case practically speaking, do you mean it would be eligible for GC when Foo is eligible ?

Comment: No when the class Loader which has loaded Test class will be eligible  for garbage collection

Comment: @AlexVPerl check my answer I have added an explanation with respect to your Test class and myVariable.

Comment: The link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html%23jls-12.7 seems broken; should presumably be to _Java Language 12.7: Unloading of Classes and Interfaces_ at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

`public` access means it is available for all. There is no distinction of `public` between `static` and `instance` variables.

> When would myVariable go out of scope ?

Not sure what you mean by variable going out of scope. Scope is public so it will be available everywhere. JVM lifetime in terms of garbage collection, depends on the reference to the class.

Comment: Thanks I meant memory scope.

Answer (score 0):

your class is public. your static member is public. It will not go out of scope.

Comment: Thanks I meant memory scope.

Comment: Please check first answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-is-a-static-method-and-a-static-variable-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-in-sta

Comment: Thanks but I did not find it insightful.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern is to when it is garbage collected. Before proceeding ahead you need to  understand memory management

Note that only the variables and their technical values (primitives or references) are stored in PermGen space.

If your static variable is a reference to an object that object itself is stored in the normal sections of the heap (young/old generation or survivor space). Those objects (unless they are interal objects like classes etc.) are not stored in PermGen space.

Example:

```
static int i = 1; //the value 1 is stored in the permgen section 
static Object o = new SomeObject(); //the reference(pointer/memory address) is stored in the permgen section, the object itself is not.
```

Comment: Thanks but you're explaining on which sections of memory variables are stored. I come from C# background so I'm familiar with heap vs stack differences, however not so much with PermGen - does that imply that object will live longer?

Comment: I strongly recommend you to go through these links that explain memory management. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html. http://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-and-garbage-collection-monitoring-tuning

Comment: Kindly let me know if you still have issues after going through the doc

Comment: Kindly let me know if your concern is resolved else kindly accept the answer and close the question

Comment: Sry @Mudassar but your reply, even though informative, but does not answer the actual question posted.

Comment: No worries buddy, just saw Sarafaraz's answer, it's more specific

Comment: What does your expression _PermGen_ mean and where does it come from? I cannot find “perm” in the page you link to, nor in its associated index.

Comment: @PJTraill have a closer look at the links mentioned, you will find it

Comment: Sorry, it is not there, but it is in [Java SE6 HotSpot VM GC Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html).

Comment: Seems you missed out reading the second link
http://www.journaldev.com/2856/java-jvm-memory-model-and-garbage-collection-monitoring-tuning which shows the understanding of permgen

Comment: Yes, sorry, I see now, I mistook it for one link abbreviated with “...” — but the Oracle reference I gave seems more informative.