# Memory area for Static methods in java

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I had studied that the static data members of class are getting memory at class loading time in the class information area (CIA) of class area,but i couldn't find out which memory area is for static methods . is it the method area in the class area ? but your answer[old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-is-a-static-method-and-a-static-variable-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-in-sta)is also saying that static variables also get memory in heap but i had read it in complete refrence that the memory is alloted in CIA and it is saying that all the methods(static and instance)get memory in heap,but instance member function get memory in method area of class area.so according to you for what the the other memory areas(method area,stack,CIA,etc) are for?

Comment: did you try google ?

Comment: yes,there are different opinions.stackoverflow said it depends on jvm,how?

Comment: Every time a method (static or instance) is *invoked*, some space is "allocated" on the current thread's *stack*, for parameters and local variables. when the method returns, the space is "popped" from stack.

Comment: i am asking about the method itself not it's variables or other information