# Memory Allocation for Singleton class Object in Java

Tags: java

In Java If we instantiate an object then it will be located at Heap memory But what happens if we instantiate a singleton class object then it object locates where ???(Heap or class area as it static reference)

Comment: Doesn't matter where the reference is, the object is always on the heap.

Comment: Side note: AFAIK, there is no "class area." The JVM has a "[*method* area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4)," but as the name suggests, it's for methods, not classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [where is a static method and a static variable stored in java. In heap or in stack memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-is-a-static-method-and-a-static-variable-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-in-sta)

Comment: then garbage collector will able to destroy singleton class object when object reference will be null. right? @Marko Topolnik

Comment: Yes, just like any other object.

Answer (score 2):

Instances that aren't purely local to methods are created and stored in the heap, even if they're only referenced from `static` fields.

(If the instance is local to a method and doesn't survive method termination, the JVM *may*, as an optimization, allocate it on the stack. Which isn't strictly applicable to your question, just explaining the caveat in the initial sentence above.)

Answer (score 0):

All created instances will be stored in the heap. so even though it is a singleton class, the only instance will be created in the heap. but that reference will be kept by a static filed. because the static filed is a part of class definition (not the instance), that reference will be stored along with the class meta data which is stored in the PermGen which is actually a part of the heap