# How to save int in a stack? (java beginner)

Tags: java, server, stack, client

I am trying to save the value of an int that my server gets from the client to a stack but do not know where to begin or what to do.

```
public class ser {
    public static int number, temp;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
    {
        ServerSocket s1=new ServerSocket(1342);
        Socket ss = s1.accept();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (ss.getInputStream());
        number = sc.nextInt();

        temp = number*2;

        PrintStream p=new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        p.println(temp);
    }
}
```

I want the temp to be saved in a stack.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need a stack first. Then since the standard implementation will accept objects only you'd need to box the `int` with an `Integer` but the compiler might do that for you automatically. If you want a stack of primitives there probably is some library containing something like an `IntStack` out there.

Comment: What is your question? You don't know how to declare variable? Which type to use for `Stack`?

Answer (score 0):

try below code.

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class ser {
    public static int number, temp;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
    {
        ServerSocket s1=new ServerSocket(1342);
        Socket ss = s1.accept();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (ss.getInputStream());
        number = sc.nextInt();

        temp = number*2;

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(); 
        stack.push(number);
        stack.push(temp);

        PrintStream p=new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        p.println(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean you want to create a stack data structure, i.e. a first in last out structure.

You need to declare a [stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) object and push your temp variable in it. The modified code would look something like this

```java
  import java.io.*; 
  import java.util.*; 

  public class ser {
      public static int number, temp;

      public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, 
  IOException 
      {
          ServerSocket s1=new ServerSocket(1342);
          Socket ss = s1.accept();
          Scanner sc = new Scanner (ss.getInputStream());
          number = sc.nextInt();

          temp = number*2;

          Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>(); 
          stack.push(temp);

          PrintStream p=new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
          // this should print your temp number, now part of the stack
          p.println(stack.peek());
      }
   }
```

However, if you are referring to the act of saving variables "on stack" as the memory allocation are, do take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-are-static-methods-and-static-variables-stored-in-java) question.

Hope this helps!