# Where is the static method in the static class going in terms of RAM

Tags: static, static-methods, ram

I have general knowledge of how the static variable works where it's saved in RAM. But what if the static class has a method having more than 1000 + lines, then where is it gone and use it for the lift time of the application. I understand that that could a duplicate question. If anybody answered to this question, please reply below.

```
public static class staticClass
{
    public static int LongMethod()
    {
        // more than 1000 lines in this method  
    }

}
```

Comment: `static` on a method doesn't affect how its code is stored in memory; instead it means that you call it without a particular object.

Comment: @NateEldredge let's say someone added like 10000 lines in the static method inside the static class. How the method is being used in terms of the Memory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are static methods and static variables stored in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-are-static-methods-and-static-variables-stored-in-java)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Thank you for the answer. I read it and it's about storing static variables. I know the static variables might be stored in the heap. If the method is super large, then its it still saved in the heap same as variables?