# Is static immutable set and list immediately promoted to old gen in java 17 with G1 (hotspot VM)

Tags: java, g1gc

For example

```
class myClass {
    public static final Set<String> s2 = Set.of("val1", "val2".........);
}
```

Once the class is loaded, where does jvm store these static sets in memory? Does it go through eden -> survivor -> tenured? Or straight to tenured?

Will jvm ever deallocate the static object once its allocated?

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-are-static-methods-and-static-variables-stored-in-java

Comment: Thanks for the comment
I think the answer to the question does not answer this question 
`If your static variable is a reference to an object that object itself is stored in the normal sections of the heap (young/old generation or survivor space). Those objects (unless they are internal objects like classes etc.) are not stored in PermGen space.`I would like to know if static object that are not of primitive value directly go to tenure space or not
thanks

Comment: No, the Java memory allocator doesn't provide special handling for these objects. It only provides special handling for large objects. Anything else would make an already complex code even more complex for very little gain.