# Android NDK UnsatisfiedLinkError: "dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH"

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, linker, java-native-interface

I am tracking down crashes with our Android application (which uses the NDK to load a custom C++ library) using a crash reporting service. A small number of users are experiencing the following crash:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: empty/missing DT_HASH in "cpplibrary.so" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)
   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
```

The couple of mentions of this error I can find on the internet (for example this [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Android-ndk/4-_PpwySQIo)) discuss problems with building the libs, which cause this error to occur every time the app is run.  There is little information on why this might happen sporadically.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645249/intermittent-android-ndk-unsatisfiedlinkerror) is the closest I can find.

Based on the crash traces, it looks like any particular user will experience this constantly for stretches; I am not sure if these users are ever able to load the lib correctly. Does anyone have ideas on what might cause this to happen only sometimes? Can I do the NDK build differently to try and stop it?

Thanks!

Edit: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818058/android-ndk-unsatisfiedlinkerror-a-surprising-reason) mentions two ways to get such errors conditionally; I will be looking in to them.

Edit2: Build files:
Android.mk (excerpt):

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := <Source Path>...
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID -Wall
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -DENABLE_SDK_DEBUGGING=1 -DENABLE_SDK_LOGGING=1
LOCAL_MODULE := cpplibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <Source Files> / ...

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cpplibrary
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_CFLAGS += -std=c++11
```

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this? I'm having the same issue with a native library I'm building. Very few users see it, but some are getting a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError caused by an `empty/missing DT_HASH in "libGLESv3.so" (built with --hash-style=gnu?)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're a third party building .so libraries for others to use, setting `-Wl,--hash-style=both` seems like the best idea. That gets you the faster loading of the Gnu-style hash and the backwards compatibility of the SysV hash.

If you're only supporting Android 8 and later, there's no need to support the SysV hash.

Comment: No longer have access to the app issue was filed for, but I agree this seems to be the best possible advice.  Quick Google suggests this problem spiked in 2015, then faded away, with anecdotal evidence for a bug in ReLinker.  In any event, if you as a third party lib dev set it to 'both', I think you've done your due diligence.

Answer (score 3):

The library you are trying to load was most likely built with `-Wl,--hash-style=gnu`. This was not supported on Android until recently (afaik this isn't even in L). You need to build your libraries with `-Wl,--hash-style=sysv`.

How did you build `cpplibrary.so`? If you didn't do anything to manually switch to the gnu hash style, it could be a bug in the NDK.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am not currently setting the hash style anywhere.  I can try explicitly setting it to sysv but because so few users encounter it I won't see results until our next app release. I will try it and see if anything different happens.

Comment: I have the same problem. As my problem is with a third party cpplibrary.so I cant simply build the library with `-Wl,--hash-style=sysv'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tell the author of the third party library that they're building it wrong. That's the only possible fix if you want to continue using that library.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced this problem while using Android Cmake and I have set
`-DANDROID_PLATFORM=23` 
As per [changelog](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/50640170c652966c439a107d01a5e109cc496194/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#gnu-hashes-availible-in-api-level-23) The GNU hash style becomes available from API 23 and because of `ANDROID_PLATFORM` was set to 23 the flag `--hash-style=gnu` was set automatically.

I have fixed this just by lowering `-DANDROID_PLATFORM=21`and then the flag was set to the flag `--hash-style=both`

Answer (score 1):

Although out of this question, I met this problem in Android Studio import third-party so file. Finally I found this is because Gradle automatically stripped the product 'so' file, so disabling this option it works.

```html
android {
 ........
    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
    }
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`--hash-style=both` should work. Check https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#gnu-hashes-availible-in-api-level-23 as refs.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to different arhitectures of target devices. Are you able to collect device vendor/model information from crash reports ? 
Not sure, but I guess you need to compile you native library across multiple archs (armeabi, armeabi-v7, neon) to overcome such incompabilities.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good suggestion.  That was one of my first suspicions for the problems, but all the devices with the crash are armeabi-v7, which we support.  Also, the crashes are not 100% for every device; we have a Samsung S5 that works fine, but that is one of the crashing phones.

Answer (score 0):

To see if it is hash-style problem you can run readelf -d cpplibrary.so and look for GNU_HASH section. If there is one - --hash-style=sysv should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is building a Rust library for Flutter using [this project template](https://github.com/brickpop/flutter-rust-ffi), changing corresponding line in the `makefile` to `ANDROID_ARMV7_LINKER=$(ANDROID_NDK_HOME)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/$(OS_NAME)-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi22-clang` will help.